# Which numbers represent the keys on your keyboard?

Tags: jquery

I wondered which numbers represent which keys on your keyboard, for example, I know 65 represents `a`, but which number would represents `s`?

I couldn't find it anywhere. If I didn't search like I should have, please redirect me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitively use jQuery for this. It's the best.

Comment: My [jquery.key](https://github.com/danheberden/jquery-key) plugin has a `$().key('help')` command to help you find out (and use) that key code.

Comment: Note that there is no innate number system for keys on your keyboard. It all depends which programmatic API or language you're dealing with.

Comment: If you are on a Unix system open a terminal and type `man ascii`

Comment: You should accept an answer rather than retitling your question as [SOLVED]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had a few minutes and so I wrote this (which should allow you to find the key-code of any given key, or keys, on your keyboard):

```
function keyMap(start, stop) {
    var startFrom, stopAt, o = {};

    // doing different things, depending on what the 'start' variable is:
    switch (typeof start) {
        // if it's a string, we need the character-code, so we get that:
        case 'string':
            startFrom = start.charCodeAt(0);
            break;
        // if it's already a number, we use that as-is:
        case 'number':
            startFrom = start;
            break;
        // whatever else it might be, we quit here:
        default:
            return '';
    }

    // similarly for the 'stop' variable:
    switch (typeof stop) {
        case 'string':
            stopAt = stop.charCodeAt(0);
            break;
        case 'number':
            stopAt = stop;
            break;
        // if it's neither a number, nor a string,
        default:
            /* but start has a length of at least 2, and start is a string,
               we use the second character of the start string, or
               we simply add 1 to the character-code from the start variable: */
            stopAt = start.length > 1 && typeof start === 'string' ? start.charCodeAt(1) : startFrom;
            break;
    }

    /* iterate over the character-codes (using 'len = stopAt + 1 because we
       want to include the ending character): */
    for (var i = startFrom, len = stopAt + 1; i < len; i++) {
        // setting the keys of the 'o' map, and the value stored therein:
        o[String.fromCharCode(i)] = i;
    }
    return o;
}

var map = keyMap('s');
console.log(map, map['s'], map.s);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sT4H9/1/).

Or, to find a range of keycodes:

```
var map = keyMap('a','z');
console.log(map, map.a, map.b, map.c /* ...and so on... */);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sT4H9/3/).

Or, to find the same range, but with only one supplied argument:

```
var map = keyMap('az');
console.log(map, map.a, map.b, map.c /* ...and so on... */);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sT4H9/4/).

References:

- [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
- [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).
- [`switch () {...}` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Decimal values in The ascii table [HERE](http://www.asciitable.com/). Lower-case `s` is 115.

Comment: Lower-case `s` is 115

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is the link to all the keyCodes.. however you can always try it yourself ..

using jquery

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  alert(e.keyCode);
  //or
  alert(e.which);
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrFmY/)

Comment: you can use e.which or e.keyCode , with jquery it is normalized.. so doesnot matter...

Comment: Saw this in documentation page `"The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input."`

Comment: yaaa.. already added that to answer too.. :) ...as said it is normalized with jquery so i guess we can reliably use both ...

Comment: My bad, I did not read the article `:p`